# Validating through terraform that a vault policy exists before using it in a group

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp, terraform-modules

I have the following structure

```
module "policies" {
  source   = "../../../../path/to/my/custom/modules/groups"
  for_each = var.config.policies

  name   = each.key
  policy = each.value
}

module "groups" {
  source   = "../../../../path/to/my/custom/modules/groups"
  for_each = var.config.groups

  name     = each.key
  type     = each.value.type
  policies = each.value.policies
  depends_on = [
    module.policies
  ]
}
```

Policies and groups are declared in a `yaml` file from which through `yamldecode` the corresponding variables to `for_each` are created.

Is there any way to make sure that the policies passed to `policies = each.value.policies` of the `groups` module **DO** exist?

I mean, OK I have the `depends_on` clause, but I want to also provision for typos in the `yaml` file and other similar situations.

Comment: You can use https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/try, but it will not catch any YAML related errors.

Comment: I am not saying whether they do exist in my `yaml`; I want to make sure the corresponding `terraform` resource (that corresponds to the policy name `my-policy`) has been created and the policy exists in `vault`; If I pass a policy named `foobar` and the policy does not exist in `vault`, the group will still be created

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to declare a dependency on an external object (managed elsewhere) in Terraform is to use a `data` block using a data source defined by the provider responsible for that object. If the goal is only to verify that the object exists then it's enough to declare the data source and then have your downstream object's configuration refer to *anything* about its result, just so Terraform can see that the data source is a dependency and so should be resolved first.

Unfortunately it seems like the `hashicorp/vault` provider doesn't currently have a data source for declaring a dependency on a policy, although there is [a feature request for it](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-vault/issues/1516).

Assuming that it *did* exist then the pattern might look something like this:

```
data "vault_policy" "needed" {
  for_each = var.config.policies

  name = each.value
}

module "policies" {
  source   = "../../../../path/to/my/custom/modules/groups"
  for_each = var.config.policies

  name = each.key

  # Accessing this indirectly via the data resource tells
  # Terraform that it must complete the data lookup before
  # planning anything which depends on this "policy" argument.
  policy = data.vault_policy.needed[each.key].name
}
```

---

Without a data source for this particular object type I don't think there will be an elegant way to solve this, but you may be able to work around it by using a more general data source like `hashicorp/external`'s [`external` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) for collecting data by running an external program that prints JSON.

Again because you don't actually seem to need any specific data from the policy and only want to check whether it exists, it would be sufficient to write an external program which queries vault and then exists with an unsuccessful status if the request fails, or prints an empty JSON object `{}` if the request succeeds.

```
data "external" "vault_policy" {
  for_each = var.config.policies

  program = ["${path.module}/query-vault"]

  query = {
    policy_name = each.value
  }
}

module "policies" {
  source   = "../../../../path/to/my/custom/modules/groups"
  for_each = var.config.policies

  name   = each.key
  policy = data.external.vault_policy.query.policy_name
}
```

I'm not familiar enough with Vault to suggest a specific implementation of this `query-vault` program, but you may be able to use a shell script wrapping the `vault` CLI program if you follow the advice in [Processing JSON in shell scripts](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source#processing-json-in-shell-scripts). You only need to do the input parsing part of that, because your result would be communicated either by `exit 1` to signal failure or `echo '{}'` followed by exiting successfully to signal success.

Comment: "I'm not familiar enough with Vault to suggest a specific implementation of this query-vault program" Fortunately I am very familiar with this kind of Vault tooling, and one would generally look to leverage SDK bindings with an endpoint such as https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/system/policies#list-acl-policies. As for the specific bindings: I can personally vouch for Go (Hashi module), Ruby (Vargo's), Python (HVAC), Node.js (nodevault), C++17 (libvault), and Rust (hashicorp_vault) as all being up to the task here.

Comment: Additionally one could also simply use the Vault statically linked executable with a JSON formatted output to query the policy if the executable is part of the build agent image in the pipeline (assuming TF executed in a pipeline, which it generally is at most companies):https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/policy/list.

Comment: All that being said, this answer is definitely the best practices at this current moment in time for a Vault+TF integration to solve the use case for the stated question; with the caveat that one would want to probably query for all policies simultaneously in the external data source, and not iterate through the enumerable.